# Missing io.h for netCDF4 installation for Python3 on Windows8

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

I am trying to install the netCDF4 package for Python 3 on my Windows 8 PC. I have already worked through some bugs like adding the visual studio directory to PATH. However, I don't make good headway with the current issue:

when I run

```
pip install netcdf4
```

the output indicates that the file `io.h` could not be found. In fact, a search across the `C:/` directory shows that I don't have this file on my PC.

An internet search indicates that the file `io.h` is somewhat outdated and not used anymore. Is there a way that I can get it from somewhere?

Is there a place where I can

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error, I found a solution and I hope that by posting it here it might save somebody else some time.

The only Visual Studio environment that I had installed was `Visual Studio Community 2017`. What solved my problem was that, additionally, I installed the default (= not changing any of the default modules) version of [Visual Studio 2017 Desktop Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/express/). Afterwards,

```
pip install netcdf4
```

worked flawlessly.